# Semantic correctness onclick on div

Tags: javascript, html

Is it wrong to have click event handlers attached to divs or spans which do not have any semantic meaning by themselves?

```
<div id="my-div"></div>
<script>
    var el = document.getElementById("my-div");
    el.addEventListener("click", function() {
       alert('div clicked but does it make sence?')
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: I tend to add actions that isn't related to route change into a button but I don't think it's wrong to do it on anything else. In fact, even if you click on a button, that event will also bubble-up to it's parents elements. And we often see click handler on div or even body to close a modal.

Comment: The fact that you've added an `id` to the element gives it semantic meaning. So, no, it's not incorrect to do this.